# How to configure XCMP queue drop threshold?

Tags: polkadot, runtime, xcmp, configuration

The XCMP queue [drops messages if they exceed the limit](https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/blob/37aa2a8c5d84ce4bc8d7f4d47451cb3fcf2b8ae4/pallets/xcmp-queue/src/lib.rs#L994-L1001):

```
if (count as u32) < drop_threshold {
    status[i].message_metadata.push((sent_at, format));
} else {
    debug_assert!(
        false,
        "XCMP channel queue full. Silently dropping message"
    );
}
```

The [default config value of 5](https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/blob/37aa2a8c5d84ce4bc8d7f4d47451cb3fcf2b8ae4/pallets/xcmp-queue/src/lib.rs#L471) will drop once 5 XCMP messages pile up which seems way too eager to drop for production use.

How should the queue be configured?
Is the HRMP channel max capacity a reasonable value (so that in the extreme case of the whole HRMP queue being filled all those messages will be processed by the xcmp queue pallet)?